# Problem with babel and tikzcd

Tags: babel, tikz-cd

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[italian]{standalone}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
  A \arrow[dr, "\psi\phi"'] \arrow[r, "\phi"] & B \arrow[d, "\psi"] \\
                                 & C
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

It gives this error during compilation:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\italian@sh@"@ ...it@next {''}\else \def \it@next 
                                                  {\futurelet \it@temp \it@c...
l.12 \end{tikzcd}
```

If you remove the `[italian]` option, it compiles nicely, providing the expected figure
[image]

Yet, I have used the `babel` library in `tikz`, as suggested in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163929/tikz-shortandoff-on-newcommand-problem) and in [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166772/problem-with-babel-and-tikz-using-draw) or [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/531207/interference-between-babel-and-tikzcd).

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: as requested, I include the log file

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=latex 2023.5.31)  27 NOV 2023 17:08
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**p2.tex
(./p2.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-01-21> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.cls
Document Class: standalone 2018/03/26 v1.3a Class to compile TeX sub-files standalone
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/shellesc.sty
Package: shellesc 2019/11/08 v1.0c unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
Package shellesc Info: Restricted shell escape enabled on input line 77.
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2020/11/20 v2.8 package option processing (HA)
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks16
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks17

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))
\XKV@depth=\count185
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
\sa@internal=\count186
\c@sapage=\count187
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.cfg
File: standalone.cfg 2018/03/26 v1.3a Default configuration file for 'standalone' class
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count188
\c@section=\count189
\c@subsection=\count190
\c@subsubsection=\count191
\c@paragraph=\count192
\c@subparagraph=\count193
\c@figure=\count194
\c@table=\count195
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
\sa@box=\box50
\sa@yoffset=\skip49
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
Package: babel 2022/01/26 3.70 The Babel package
\babel@savecnt=\count196
\U@D=\dimen139
\l@unhyphenated=\language10
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def)
\bbl@readstream=\read2
\bbl@dirlevel=\count197
 (/home/user/tex/texinputs/italian.ldf
Language: italian 2005/11/17 v1.2r Italian support from the babel system
Package babel Info: Making " an active character on input line 91.
Now handling font encoding LGR ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding LGR

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/greek-inputenc/lgrenc.dfu
File: lgrenc.dfu 2019/07/11 1.7 UTF-8 support for Greek
   defining Unicode char U+00A8 (decimal 168)
   ... a few similar lines deleted
   defining Unicode char U+10146 (decimal 65862)
   defining Unicode char U+10147 (decimal 65863)
))) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks18
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen140
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen141
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box51
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)
Package: pgfrcs 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
))
Package: pgf 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2021/03/04 v1.4d Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: dvips.def on input line 107.
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/dvips.def
File: dvips.def 2017/06/20 v3.1d Graphics/color driver for dvips
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen142
\Gin@req@width=\dimen143
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
Package: pgfsys 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks19
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks20

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks21
))
\pgf@x=\dimen144
\pgf@y=\dimen145
\pgf@xa=\dimen146
\pgf@ya=\dimen147
\pgf@xb=\dimen148
\pgf@yb=\dimen149
\pgf@xc=\dimen150
\pgf@yc=\dimen151
\pgf@xd=\dimen152
\pgf@yd=\dimen153
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read3
\c@pgf@counta=\count198
\c@pgf@countb=\count199
\c@pgf@countc=\count266
\c@pgf@countd=\count267
\t@pgf@toka=\toks22
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks23
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks24
\pgf@sys@id@count=\count268
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg
File: pgf.cfg 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-dvips.def
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-dvips.def
File: pgfsys-dvips.def 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-postscript.def
File: pgfsys-common-postscript.def 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgf@objectcount=\count269
))) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count270
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count271
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2021/10/31 v2.13 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: dvips.def on input line 227.
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1372.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1373.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1374.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1375.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
Package: pgfcore 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen154
\pgfmath@count=\count272
\pgfmath@box=\box52
\pgfmath@toks=\toks25
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks26
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks27
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics.code.tex)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count273
)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen155
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen156
\pgf@picminy=\dimen157
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen158
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen159
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen160
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen161
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen162
\pgf@xx=\dimen163
\pgf@xy=\dimen164
\pgf@yx=\dimen165
\pgf@yy=\dimen166
\pgf@zx=\dimen167
\pgf@zy=\dimen168
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen169
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen170
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen171
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen172
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgfpic=\box53
\pgf@hbox=\box54
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box55
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count274
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen173
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen174
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen175
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen176
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen177
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgf@max=\dimen178
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count275
\pgf@shadingcount=\count276
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box56
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.tex
File: pgfcorerdf.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box57
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen179
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen180
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
Package: pgffor 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)
\pgffor@iter=\dimen181
\pgffor@skip=\dimen182
\pgffor@stack=\toks28
\pgffor@toks=\toks29
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
Package: tikz 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count277
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen183
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen184
\tikz@lasty=\dimen185
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen186
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen187
\tikz@lastmovetox=\dimen188
\tikz@lastmovetoy=\dimen189
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen190
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen191
\tikz@figbox=\box58
\tikz@figbox@bg=\box59
\tikz@tempbox=\box60
\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box61
\tikztreelevel=\count278
\tikznumberofchildren=\count279
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count280
\tikz@fig@count=\count281

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count282
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count283
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count284
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count285
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
))) (/home/user/tex/texinputs/tikzlibrarycd.code.tex (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarymatrix.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarymatrix.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryquotes.code.tex
File: tikzlibraryquotes.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryarrows.meta.code.tex
File: pgflibraryarrows.meta.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgfarrowinset=\dimen192
\pgfarrowlength=\dimen193
\pgfarrowwidth=\dimen194
\pgfarrowlinewidth=\dimen195
)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarybabel.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarybabel.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.def
File: l3backend-dvips.def 2022-01-12 L3 backend support: dvips
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box62
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count286
\l__pdf_backend_content_box=\box63
\l__pdf_backend_model_box=\box64
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count287
\g__pdf_backend_link_int=\count288
\g__pdf_backend_link_sf_int=\count289
) (./p2.aux)
\openout1 = `p2.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for LGR/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for LGR+cmr on input line 8.
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cbfonts-fd/lgrcmr.fd
File: lgrcmr.fd 2017/07/29 v1.2 Greek European Computer Regular
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 10.

! Undefined control sequence.
\italian@sh@"@ ...it@next {''}\else \def \it@next 
                                                  {\futurelet \it@temp \it@c...
l.12 \end{tikzcd}
                 
? x
 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 14292 strings out of 480123
 302567 string characters out of 5893104
 595571 words of memory out of 5000000
 32040 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 469259 words of font info for 28 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 81 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 100i,13n,104p,457b,939s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
No pages of output.
```

Comment: Your code compiles without error for me. Is your tex distribution up-to-date? Can you show your .log file so we can see which package versions etc. you use?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz The log file is quite long: how can I show it? In any case, I use latex on Linux Mint 21 (Vanessa), so I think it should be quite up to date. In particular, tkz is v3.1.9a and babel is 3.70

Comment: What is the first say 5 lines of your log? It gives us some idea about the age of your LaTeX dist

Comment: The current babel version is  v3.97 and tikz is v3.1.10

Comment: The example compiles without errors for me on TL23,22,21,20,19

Comment: Also check the log to see if you have a stray manual file somewhere, that is shadowing a file from the installation.

Comment: For me the log file is less than 500 linies. I do not remember the upper limit for the about of lines in a question on the site.

Comment: @daleif : log is 718 lines

Comment: How can I attach it? Just include it as code in the question?

Comment: You can edit the question and past it to it as code, yes.

Comment: It compiles fine with every distribution Overleaf has to offer and they go back to 2014 ... It seems unlikely that it is a version issue, I'd say.

Comment: I  can't attach the full log: it is 35569 characters and there is a limit of 30000 :( I will attach just the first lines

Comment: Is the error you show the first error in the log? Often, the first error is the one that shows the real problem.

Comment: Now the log is attached: I just deleted a few similar lines

Comment: `Language: italian 2005/11/17 v1.2r Italian support from the babel system
Package babel Info: Making " an active character on input line 91.` > Your Italian package for babel is quite old. Try to update it.

Comment: Ok, problem solved! I had a very old Italian support from a very old babel installation which survived upon reinstallation of the system and I was not aware of it. My bad... :( Many thanks to everybody

Comment: @JasperHabicht If you would put your comment as answer, I will accept it.